# vcan0 interface linux communication

Tags: linux, can-bus, socketcan

Linux is supporting virtual can interface. it was enabled by:

```
modprobe vcan
sudo ip link add dev vcan0 type vcan
sudo ifconfig vcan0 up
```

While using `cam-utils` such as `camsniffer` and `cansend`

```
cansend vcan0 321#1212
cansniffer vcan0
```

I could able to see can packets; but only within same host. I tried Ubuntu VirtualBox machine. Both guest and host OS are interconnected using host-only adapter `vboxnet0`.

Also tried SocketCAN `socket(PF_CAN, SOCK_RAW, CAN_RAW)` but not able to receive on other machine(works within same machine) While trying with broadcast manager `socket(PF_CAN, SOCK_DGRAM, CAN_BCM)` on executing `stderr` says `operation not supported

Simply, could one send and receive CAN packets between Linux hosts? Doesn't matter its Virtual Machine (vboxnet0) or physically connected (Ethernet).

Note: I used Ubuntu 16.04 and 12.04 as Host and Guest OS respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CAN uses its own physial bus. The `vcan` devices are designed for testing software that communicates over the bus without requiring an actual physical connection, they're not actually supplied by the hypervisor, but are a part of SocketCAN.

By the looks of it, you're attempting to establish a Virtual CAN bus in Virtualbox, connecting multiple machines together as though they all had CAN controllers and were connected to a physical bus. I've looked, but it appears that such functionality doesn't exist, and beyond writing an extension for VirtualBox, is probably not likely to.

Is there a specific reason you're looking to use CAN? Trying to pull data from an ECU or communicate with embedded hardware that has a CAN controller? As far as desktop pc communication, ethernet is much more convenient, faster,a nd well supported.

Comment: Learning to set-up a virtual environment for car simulation. Example, door lock simulation. A program is written to toggle driver door lock/unlock; results in 3 remaining door get CAN message and locks/unlocks automatically. The programs just showing message Locked/unlocked on screen.